# The method put(String, ArrayList<Integer>) in the type TreeMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean)

Tags: java, put, treemap

I'm getting an error on this line

```
tm.put(temp[j],tm.get(temp[j]).add(i));
```

when i was compiling my program in eclipse:

```
The method put(String, ArrayList<Integer>) in the type TreeMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean)
```

The followings are my codes:

```
TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> tm=new TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
String[] temp=folders.split(" |,");
for (int j=1;j<temp.length;j++){

            if (!tm.containsKey(temp[j])){
                tm.put(temp[j], new ArrayList<Integer>(j));
            } else {
                tm.put(temp[j],tm.get(temp[j]).add(j));
            }
        }
```

the *folders* is something like this

```
folders="0 Jim,Cook,Edward";
```

I'm wondering why there's no error on the former *put* method, but only on the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList.add(E)` returns a `boolean`, you simply cannot chain them up.

`tm.get(temp[j]).add(j);` is enough, you don't need to `put` again.

`new ArrayList<Integer>(j)` won't give you an arraylist of one element, the argument is the initialCapacity.

Then, you should declare `tm` as `Map<String, List<Integer>>`.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> tm=new TreeMap<String, List<Integer>>();
String[] temp=folders.split(" |,");
for (int j=1;j<temp.length;j++){

    if (!tm.containsKey(temp[j])){
        tm.put(temp[j], new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }
    tm.get(temp[j]).add(j); // This will change the arraylist in the map.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList.add(E)` returns a `boolean` value, and thus, you can't incorporate the call within a single statement.

You need to pass an `ArrayList<Integer>` object as the second argument to the `put` method.

Answer (score 0):

[`ArrayList::add` returns true in this scenario](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28java.lang.Object%29); that is, it doesn't return the new ArrayList. Try cloning the list, adding to it, and then passing it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)

public boolean add(E e)
 Appends the specified element to the end of this list and returns a boolean. Hence, the error.